# Stargazer missing some output variables for multivariate regression table

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

I am trying to do a multivariate regression, and output the results through stargazer.

My multivariate code:

```
lm(formula = adjlife_mill ~ bud + mpaa1 + sequel + rating + action + 
drama + noms, data = movies2022)
```

[Summary Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z8vU.png)

[Stargazer Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQFvJ.png)

My output showed my Estimate Std.

But I am missing my Error, T- Value, and Probability columns.

```
stargazer(multi, type="html", header = FALSE, title = "Multivariate Regression Output", digits = 3, dep.var.labels=c("Estimate Std","Error", "T-Value", "Pr(>|t|"), covariate.labels=c("Budget","MPAA G","MPAA PG","MPAA R","Sequels","Rotten Tomatos Ratings", "Action", "Drama", "Nominations",  flip=TRUE))
```

Comment: I don't think stargazer is intended to provide all this information.  The t-statistics and p-values are redundant with the coefficient and standard error, so it omits those pieces of information in the interest of parsimony.

Comment: What about something like `knits::kable(summary(multi)$coef)` if you want all of the redundant pieces of information.